# React | How to interpolate value from an input into API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, interpolation

I have two textboxes, one for latitude and one for longitude. I'm trying to interpolate them into the url like I did with my API key.

What would be the easiest way of doing this?

```
async function sendAPIRequest (){
let res = await fetch(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/assets?lon=-95.33&lat=29.78&date=2018-01-01&&dim=0.10&api_key=${API_KEY}`);
console.log(res);
let data = await res.json();
console.log(data);
displayData(data);
}



<input id="latID" className="input" type="text" placeholder="Lattitude" />
<input  id="longID" className="input" type="text" placeholder="Longitude" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say that a more React way to access input would be using refs and [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook, documentation for class based components [React.createRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

```
const latRef = useRef();
const longRef = useRef();

async function sendAPIRequest (){
let res = await fetch(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/assets?lon=${longRef.current.value}&lat=${latRef.current.value}&date=2018-01-01&&dim=0.10&api_key=${API_KEY}`);
console.log(res);
let data = await res.json();
console.log(data);
displayData(data);
}



<input  id="latID" ref={latRef}  className="input" type="text" placeholder="Lattitude" />
<input  id="longID" ref={longRef} className="input" type="text" placeholder="Longitude" />
```

Second option is to add state where store input value after each update:

```
const [long, setLong] = useState('');
const [lat, setLat] = useState('');

async function sendAPIRequest (){
let res = await fetch(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/assets?lon=${long}&lat=${lat}&date=2018-01-01&&dim=0.10&api_key=${API_KEY}`);
console.log(res);
let data = await res.json();
console.log(data);
displayData(data);
}

<input  id="latID" className="input" type="text" placeholder="Lattitude" onChange={event => setLat(event.target.value)} />
<input  id="longID" className="input" type="text" placeholder="Longitude" onChange={event => setLong(event.target.value)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
async function sendAPIRequest (){
    // You can access here the values
    const lat = document.getElementById("latID").value;
    const lon = document.getElementById("longID").value;

    let res = await fetch(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/assets?lon=${lon}&lat=${lat}&date=2018-01-01&&dim=0.10&api_key=${API_KEY}`);
    console.log(res);
    let data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
    displayData(data);
}

// 
// or pass as arguments when calling function:
//         
const lat = document.getElementById("latID").value;
const lon = document.getElementById("longID").value;

await sendAPIRequest(lat, lon) {
    // interpolate...
}
```